# Merge multple csv files to one and hide the header

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to merge multiple csv to one bigfile.

The script is working but I would like to have only the first header, and not one for each csv within bigfile.

How could I do it, shouldn't work with header=None?

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(inDir = r'myPath', outFile = r"outPath"): 
    os.chdir(inDir)
    fileList = glob.glob("*.csv") #generate a list of csv files using the glob method
    dfList = [] 

    for filename in fileList: 
        print (filename)
        df = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        dfList.append(df) 

    concatDf = pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0) 
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None) # export the dataframe to a csv file
```

Comment: If all the files have headers then you don't actually want `header=None` there at all

Comment: what result are you getting with the script you're presenting? all headers or no headers at all?

Comment: `header=None)` remove this bit

Comment: the result with the script above is one file with all csv concatenated, but when i scroll the rows i can still see the headers for each one the files i merged. I also tried deleting `header = None` with same result.